# Is a trustee sale winning bid all inclusive, or are prorated taxes & fees due?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, home-ownership, foreclosure, auction

Is my winning bid at a trustee sale on a foreclosed home all inclusive, or 
can the trustee make us pay prorated taxes and home owner association fees?

If we must pay the fees, when would they be due?  After I have paid the winning bid with cashiers checks at the trustee sale auction ?

(The sale is in Washington state and the trustee used a third party vendor to conduct their trustee sales at the county courthouse.  Neither the trustee nor the third party vendor would answer this question.)

Answer (score 3):

You should really ask a local attorney/RE agent, but generally HOA and RE taxes are attached to the property. If the trustee sale is by the mortgage bank, then it is likely that at closing they will require you to pay the prorated portion of the HOA fees and the taxes.

I bought a foreclosed home once directly from a bank, not through a trustee auction sale, and all the taxes and HOA dues were prorated at closing, they're not part of the bid.